# How do i set primary light/dark color to components of Material-ui ? i am using custom theme like here

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-ui

[here is link of docs of how to customize theme](https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/)

The above link has Object that we can configure the theme object. But default it take primary-main color, what if i want to access primary-dark . how to access primary dark ?

Answer (score 11):

You could set the dark theme to default like this:

```
// ... imports ... 
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    type: 'dark',
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <App />
  </MuiThemeProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

For each theme you have primary and secondary colors. For primary e.g. `primary.light`, `primary.main` and `primary.dark`.

In your component, you can access the theme variables like this:

```
// ... imports ... 
const styles = theme => ({
  darkColor: {
    color: theme.palette.primary.dark // or theme.palette.primary.main
  } 
})

const StatelessMyComponent = ({ classes }) => 
  <div className={classes.darkColor}>Look at my dark color! :)</div>;

export withStyles(styles)(StatelessMyComponent);
```

Comment: i think that you need changed `theme.palatte` to `theme.palette`

Comment: Thanks, I have fixed that!